# regular expression to validate MVC model property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, ef-database-first

I need a way to validate these

9 numeric values + V   ==> 359123404V
or
11 only numeric values 199245781248

i tried below code

```
[Display(Name = "NIC Number")]
[Required]
[RegularExpression("[0-9]{11,11}\\d)|([0-9]{9,9}+v")]
public string driverNic { get; set; }
```

[dose not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GISV.png)

weirdly enough this validates only 13 numeric char input

Comment: {11,11} seems unlikely to validate _12_ numeric values.

Comment: @ADyson sorry a typo i corrected it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regex for your case is `(^[0-9]{11,11}$)|(^[0-9]{9,9}V$)`.

For a full explanation, see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/artwE7/4).
Note that this assumes that the "V" is always uppercase.

Also see this [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6m2Xsa) for some test cases.